# I am trying to exploit port 7000/tcp afs3-fileserver

Tags: web-application, nmap, vulnerability-scanners, tcp

I have been trying to exploit a cheap smart tv box that I have bought a while ago and after my nmap scan I found that port 7000/tcp was open but researching about the port gave back not much information I even searched searchsploit and vulners for any information or vulnerabilities within the port but I couldn't find anything useful. (I am new to pentesting I would use some more knowledge)

Comment: The first step is to figure out what the device uses the various ports for. Are you able to grab a firmware image for it? Are you able to get a shell? Fuzzing may also be relevant to try.

Comment: Seconding the 'Get a firmware' image recommendation on this.  Being able to download it, and analyze what's actually running on it with binwalk/qemu will be a huge help.  You may want to check out archive.org for results from devttys0.com  That was a wonderful resource for reverse engineering firmware.

Comment: Ports don't have vulnerabilities. The things running on the port have vulnerabilities. Focus on that, not the port.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a Roku box? They have port 7000/tcp open. If so, I think it's a web service. You may want to try this: https://github.com/RoseSecurity/Abusing-Roku-APIs

Comment: Welcome to the community, but the specified link is not for research per se but rather to cause pure chaos/DoS...